# Python - How to send a correct POST/GET?

Tags: python, post, get, request, python-requests

So I have been playing around with Post/Set with API through python. I have came so far that iam using a API that I got provided by:

[image]

So what I did was first the parameters which looked like

```
payload = {
    'username': 'Stack',
    'password': 'Overflow',
    'type': '4',
    'token_params': {
        'key': '1234',
        'pageurl': 'Hellow.com'
    }
}
```

which I hope is correct done by the picture.

So now to sending the post I did...

```
ID = requests.post('http://barryme.me/api/notes', params=payload)
```

but then I am receiving:

```
<Response [500]>
Unable to complete request.
```

which I assume I must have done the URL wrong I assume. I checked the post tutorials such as [Post request tutorials](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) but it gave me no luck as I can see.

**The question is how do I send a proper POST?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is unclear but since it is a POST request, the data must probably be passed as body, not query string.

So use the `data` parameter to put the payload in request body, instead of `params` which defines the query (in-url) parameters:

```
ID = requests.post('http://barryme.me/api/notes', data=payload)
```

I guess the token_params parameter must also be changed to a string:

```
import json
payload = {
    'username': 'Stack',
    'password': 'Overflow',
    'type': '4',
    'token_params': json.dumps({
        'key': '1234',
        'pageurl': 'Hellow.com'
    })
}
```

Comment: Oh okey, I tried that and still got the same issue. Response 500. I do agree the documenation is unclear and that's all I got aswell :( So its been a pain in the ass but the method you said up there did not work by changing to data=payload. It still gave me the same response 500 - unable to complete.

Comment: try the token_params mod in my edit. If that doesn't work, ask the API provider for precisions, because the doc is clearly unhelpful.

Comment: Yay that actually worked! Thank you so much Guillaume!

Comment: Wow. It worked like 4 times and then it died and gave me 500 response again... I have no idea anymore